# Docusign Webhooks Response

Tags: python-3.x, docusignapi, webhooks, hmac

We're using the DocuSign SDK (version 3.3.0) and utilising Webhooks to receive the various envelope and recipient events that occur over the lifetime of an envelope. Connect option in docusign is used for webhooks.

I get xml response from the webhooks. But in the below link, it is mentioned that the data format of webhooks response in REST API v2.1 will be json.

https://developers.docusign.com/platform/webhooks/connect/architecture/

Can anyone please help me in getting json response from webhooks? Is the option available in docusign webhooks?

(https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-admin-guide-custom-connect-configuration-htm -- This document also talks only about xml response not json)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current XML notification format of the webhook (Connect) system will still be available.

The new option of JSON notification format is in the final stages of development. I'd look for it in a couple of months.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. But I think it would have been nice, if it were updated in the documentation.